# When using Intellij 2017.1 it repeatedly says: Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

This error pops up repeatedly whenever I try to do anything with IJ, rendering it useless. Has anyone else run into this and successfully fixed it? I'm about to fresh install and reconfigure, but decided to post here before doing something that drastic.

I've done the following to address the problem:

1. chown 777 on all config and IDE directories
2. Removed all plugins except the most well known ones such as IdeaVim
3. Clear cache & restart
4. Re-import simple POJO project and try to compile

I can't reproduce it right now, but "an internal IDE error has occured" also occurs occasionally at the same time, which says it is caused by an AbstractMethodError, with the message "Z is abstract", but I don't know if the two are related.

Comment: Please share [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder knew you'd be here to help, thanks.  I posted the latest log to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/yUmVsVtn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your IntelliJ IDEA installation is corrupted. It can be caused by the malfunction during the patch update or if you have unpacked the `.tar.gz` file into the existing directory (on top of the previous version).

Download from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and unpack into the new empty directory, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to save settings` is a generic error; it can be caused by multiple issues. Check the logfiles to find out the specific reason why it fails. That should give you more information for troubleshooting.

In my case, it turned out to be caused by a plugin. Then I saw that an update was available for that plugin. After upgrading and restarting, the error was gone. Note that in your case, it might be something else.

On my Linux installation, the logfile was stored in `~/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.2/log/idea.log`. For Windows and MacOS, [the paths are different](https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/where-does-idea-write-its-log-file-300816958.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
Looked in ~/.IntelliJIdea2018.3/system/log/idea.log.

There I found a RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot save C:\sandboxes\tias\.idea\workspace.xml.
Unable to delete an intermediate file (workspace.xml___jb_old___).
```

So I deleted the file `workspace.xml___jb_old___` (I had to restart windows, the file was in use) and the problem is solved.